# C++ Callback Function to Member Function

Tags: c++, function, callback, pointer-to-member, member-functions

I have never worked with callbacks, but the following code *should* work according to my professor's notes. It doesn't like the template and has errors about "gauss cannot appear in a constant-expression."
Note: GaussElim is a function object (gauss(mx, vector) works in previous code).

The DirichletSolver templated callback function:

```
template <class T, Vector<T> matrixAlgo(const AbstractMatrix<T>&, const Vector<T>)>
Vector<T> DirichletSolver::solve(const AbstractMatrix<T>& mx, const Vector<T> vect)
{
  return matrixAlgo(mx, vect);
}
```

The Gauss operator() overload signature:

```
template <class T>
Vector<T> operator()(const AbstractMatrix<T>& mx, const Vector<T> vect);
```

And the driver code:

```
GaussElim gauss;
DirichletSolver dir;
SymMatrix<double> mx;
Vector<double> vect;
...
dir.solve<gauss.operator()>(mx, vect);
```

What do I have to do to get this to work?

Will it work for my functor? (I have two more to implement)

Comment: There are too many logical errors to fix your code in just a few steps. 1. If `matrixAlgo` should be a member function, then its signature in a non-type template parameter is not valid, 2. If `matrixAlgo` should be a non-type template parameter, then at least its enclosing class should be passed explicitly as a type template parameter, 3. Calling `matrixAlgo` would require a parameter object, 4. Since `operator()` is a function template, you'd need to explicitly instantiate it so as to get its address. 5. ..., 6. ..., 7. ... . Please try to give more details what you need and how you see it.

Comment: I suggest that you re-write it [as shown here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca738757eb36bebd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second template parameter for `solve` is expecting a function, *not* a functor. Specifically a function with the signature `Vector<T> ()(const AbstractMatrix<T>&, const Vector<T>)` for the given template parameter `T`.

`gauss.operator()` doesn't make sense, maybe you meant `GaussElim::operator()` however that won't work either because it is a member function. If you can write whatever the implementation of `GaussElim::operator()` is as a free function you can use that as the template parameter:

```
template <class T>
Vector<T> myFunc(const AbstractMatrix<T>& mx, const Vector<T> vect)
{
    // contents of GaussElim::operator()
}
```

And then call it with

```
dir.solve<double, myFunc>(mx, vect);
```

Comment: David: I figured out that I was confused, I should be passing the algorithm functor to dir.solve() via some algorithm interface. Thank you for your help.